# What is the name of lead or connector I need to connect up this Actuator valve head?

Tags: plumbing, heating, central-heating, connectors, united-kingdom

I have a ESI ZV-222/W valve I need to connect into my central heating system in order to replace a faulty valve. The ESI ZV-222/W is a spare I have, and I do not have a lead or connector for it.

What is the name of the connector or lead that I need to purchase in order to connect it to my system?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would say it is a JST-VL male connector. Try JST.com to find, and then electronic supply stores for product.